# What does "всякий взор" mean in this context? Is it a phrase?

Tags: выражения, литература

So this is from Dostoevsky's Crime and Punishment, so I'm not sure if this an archaic 19th century expression, because I don't see how the word `взор` is being used in this sentence. Does it just mean "every kind of"?

> Но останавливаться на лестнице, слушать **всякий взор** про всю эту
> обыденную дребедень, до которой ему нет никакого дела, все эти
> приставания о платеже, угрозы, жалобы, и при этом самому
> изворачиваться, извиняться, лгать, – нет уж, лучше проскользнуть
> как-нибудь кошкой по лестнице и улизнуть, чтобы никто не видал.

I used Reverso Context and Linguee but I could not find any simple or modern uses of the phrase  `всякий взор`. The only other use of the phrase I could find was some obscure poem, which is even more difficult to understand: `Всякий взор к добру стремится, нет достоинства во зле.` from a [1946 poem by Nikolay Zabolotsky](http://www.friends-partners.org/literature/20century/zabolotsky/zabolotskygrsh5.html(opt,mozilla,mac,russian,koi8,new)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a scanning mistake, the word is:
[Вздор](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80)

> Но останавливаться на лестнице, слушать всякий вз**д**ор про всю эту
> обыденную дребедень...

Just use other sources of the text.

Answer (score 2):

As to the other part of your question, there is nothing complicated in this line:

> Всякий взор к добру стремится, нет достоинства во зле

Rough translation:

> Every look turns towards the good, there is no virtue in the evil.

Взор simply means 'look' (noun).